# Flutter : clear child Texfield when Navigator pop

Tags: flutter, navigation, rebuild

I am making the sign up of my app in Flutter and this process is on 2 pages. On the first page, I use my own class for Textfields, passing arguments to them.

When I pop from the second page to the first, I would like to reset all data from the first page. I succeed to do that but I have a problem : the text in the textfields is not cleared despite the fact that the variables that receive the content of the Textfields are reset.

It gives for the first page :

```
class Inscription1 extends StatefulWidget {
  Inscription1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Inscription1> createState() => _Inscription1State();
}

class _Inscription1State extends State<Inscription1> {
  String nom = "";
```

and

```
TextFieldInscription(hint: "Nom", updateValeur: (nouvelleValeur){setState(() {nom = nouvelleValeur;});},),
```

To pass the data to the second page and force rebuild the first page when the second page pops, I have the following in the first page

```
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Inscription2(nom: nom,)).then(remettreAZero);
```

where remettreAZero is the following function

```
FutureOr remettreAZero(value){
    setState(() {
        nom = "";
    });
    rebuildAllChildren(context);
}
```

and rebuildAllChildren

```
void rebuildAllChildren(BuildContext context) {
    void rebuild(Element el) {
      el.markNeedsBuild();
      el.visitChildren(rebuild);
    }
    (context as Element).visitChildren(rebuild);
    print("rebuild");
  }
```

All this works ("nom" is set empty) but the page still shows the TextField with the value previously entered inside.

I even tried to pass a controller argument in the TextField and adding

```
controller?.clear();
```

inside the function remettreAZero but it doesn't help.

Could you help me?

Many thanks !

Bernard

Answer (score 0):

You have to dispose your `textfield` controller like this on first screen

```
@override
  void dispose() {
    textEditingController.dispose();
  }
```